# Specific type of header

Tags: header-footer

I'm preparing my extended research abstract for submission to colleges for college applications. Right now, in my file I have a title, author, etc. What I want to do is insert a short note (preferably in grayscale or some other font that distinguishes it from the abstract) at the very top of the first page (above the title) that describes the research and names the department the abstract would be sent to etc.

How might I do this?

Comment: Did you consider inserting it as text before everything else?

Comment: Yes, but I was wondering whether this is possible, because it's somewhat more elegant, and I want to get better at LaTeX.

Comment: If something is on a single page only, there is no benefit putting it as  a header.

Comment: Have you considered http://anorien.csc.warwick.ac.uk/mirrors/CTAN/macros/latex/contrib/titling/titling.pdf?

Comment: It has a \pretitle setting which might be useful.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So you could do something like this, though I'm not sure if it is what you are looking for:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{titling}
\usepackage{xcolor}% specify driver e.g. [pdftex] if custom configuration requires it; omit otherwise for maximum portability
\newcommand{\myprelude}{}
\newcommand{\prelude}[1]{%
  \renewcommand{\myprelude}{#1}}
\makeatletter
\pretitle{%
  \if\myprelude\@empty\relax
  \else
    \centering\textcolor{black!75}{\myprelude}
  \fi%
  \begin{center}\LARGE}
\makeatother

\author{Some B. Ody}
\title{Really great stuff}
\prelude{Some stuff before.}

\begin{document}
\maketitle

\begin{abstract}
    Here is my abstract.
\end{abstract}

Here is my article.

\end{document}
```

[image]

I'm not sure if that's what you meant by greyscale. Greyscale is just black-white-grey etc. as opposed to mere black-and-white, on the one hand, or a full-blown colour model, on the other. So in itself that just really means you don't want it in colour. Maybe this is because you have everything else in blue but I've guessed that you really meant you did not want it to be as strongly coloured i.e. grey rather than black. Adjust the 75 to suit. (Increase it to make the text darker; decrease it to make it lighter. 100 for black; 0 for white.)

EDIT: Option to xcolor may be omitted - thanks to egreg for pointing this out.

Comment: Thank you very much! This will definitely work, and yes, I did mean gray rather than black.

Comment: Glad it helps. If this answers your question, you can consider accepting it. Or you can wait to see if somebody offers a better answer.

Comment: Don't use the `pdftex` option to `xcolor`, which is able to get it from the engine used.

Comment: @egreg: That's odd. I tried without it first and it gave me an error so I went back and specified it. (I'd expected it to autodetect as well.)

Comment: OK. I guess my personal configuration requires the option even though the error I get is thrown by xcolor.sty. I can omit it if I compile with a fake TEXMFHOME setting.

Answer (score 1):

Anothe option could be this one,  without `titling`

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{article}
```

The `notitlepage` places the title and abstract on the same page. The article class defaults to
`notitlepage`. In case you want a separate title page then, you can pass option as `titlepage`

```
\usepackage{xcolor}% here we can use gray color
\title{What ever title you have}
\author{ABC}
%\date{} uncomment if you want date to be 'Removed'
\begin{document}
\centering{\textcolor{gray}{What ever you want to write here}}
{\let\newpage\relax\maketitle}%\since maketitle inserts a \newpage
\maketitle
\begin{abstract}
Here goes your abstract
\end{abstract}
\end{document}
```

[image]